# How to add duplicate word using regular expression?

Tags: regex

Instead of removing duplicate words using regular expression, how do I duplicate a word? My case: I have a list of emails that need to be turn to SQL queries.

```
buddy@gmail.com
melinda@yahoo.co.uk
terrence12@gmail.com
```

To:

```
mysql -e "select * from users where email='buddy@gmail.com" > /tmp/buddy@gmail.com.xls
mysql -e "select * from users where email='melinda@yahoo.co.uk" > /tmp/melinda@yahoo.co.uk.xls
mysql -e "select * from users where email='terrence12@gmail.com" > /tmp/terrence12@gmail.com.xls
```

So how do I duplicate the email in every line?

Note: Each of this query will return more than one row, that's why I'm doing each query individually.

Answer (score 2):

```
s/(.*)/mysql -e "select * from users where email='\1' > /tmp/\1.xls/
```

Comment: can you please example how \1 will substitute email address?

Answer (score 1):

Find Pattern:

```
(.+)
```

Replace Pattern:

```
mysql \-e "select \* from users where email='$1" \> /tmp/$1\.xls\r\n
```

**How it works:**
(.+): captures a line till its end (before newline character)
$1: is the captured group

Note: '-' and '*' are escaped.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex

psedocode:

```
for each line
  set email = line // line should be trimmed of newlines
  append 'mysql -e "select * from users where email=\'$email\' > /tmp/$email.xls"' to filename
end
```